# Update a json file with values from a dynamodb table in lambda with Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a json file containing the following elements: id, firstname, lastname, email
I also have a dynamodb table with the same fields. This is what I would like to do.

Each time I upload the json file into an s3 bucket, I trigger a lambda
Lambda will compare ids in the json to those in the dynamodb table.
If ids match then update firstname, lastname and email in json file
Output the json file to another s3 bucket

AWS Lambda Function

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ##Get data from s3 bucket
    bucket = 'test-bucket'
    key = 'input.json'
    
    s3response = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    content = s3response['Body']
    s3data = json.loads(content.read())
    
    ##Get data from DynamoDB table
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')

    dbresponse = table.scan()
    dynamodbdata = dbresponse['Items']

    ##Update values in s3 json with values from DynamoDB
    s3data.update((k,v) for k,v in dynamodbdata.items())
    
    #Return new dictionary for s3data
    return s3data
```

Sample json file below:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Nikolas","last_name":"Philipard","email":"nphilipard0@shutterfly.com"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Al","last_name":"Harden","email":"aharden1@foxnews.com"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Lamar","last_name":"Joinsey","email":"ljoinsey2@arstechnica.com"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Vicky","last_name":"Picker","email":"vpicker3@bluehost.com"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Thomasina","last_name":"Trowl","email":"ttrowl4@joomla.org"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Lyon","last_name":"Vassay","email":"lvassay5@t-online.de"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Terrye","last_name":"Mereweather","email":"tmereweather6@skyrock.com"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Kathryne","last_name":"d'Escoffier","email":"kdescoffier7@cam.ac.uk"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Ewart","last_name":"Hebden","email":"ehebden8@youku.com"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Mellisa","last_name":"Feetham","email":"mfeetham9@booking.com"}]
```

Comment: Hey, and welcome to StackOverflow! This question is unclear; what have you tried, and where are you struggling? Please be aware that SO is not a service where people will write your software for you. We're happy to help with concrete problems, though.